# Are there any test input and output vectors for the variant 4 PoW of Monero out there?

Tags: proof-of-work

Trying to play around with implementations, and want to be sure the baseline I've put together is correct.  It appears that in the Monero Project github, the test vectors only go up to variant 2.

Answer (score 2):

There are test vectors for CNv4 in https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/release-v0.13/tests/hash/tests-slow-4.txt